# convert color hex values for use in three.js json files

Tags: javascript, json, colors, three.js

Question - when I use the three.js editor it outputs an app.json file where color values are listed as an integer, for example:

```
"materials": [
{
    "uuid": "26C18ACF-3733-4B92-AC67-E25A132B27D0",
    "type": "MeshPhongMaterial",
    "color": 16777215,
```

I want to modify that color directly in the JSON file to some hex or RGBA equivalent, but I have no idea how to convert to whatever system of color this JSON file is using. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the three.js library to convert base 10 color values to hex:

```
var c = new THREE.Color( 123456789 ).getHexString();
console.log( '0x' + c  );
```

Or using Google, simply type

```
0xff0000 in base 10
```

or

```
16711680 in hex
```

three.js r.74